# BitmapFactory.DecodeResource does not recognise drawables

Tags: android, image, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to load a simple image as a background for a GPS app using C# in Visual Studio.

The resources are located in

> Resources/drawable/*resource file*

Now I've been trying to display these files like this, "Arrow" en "Map"

> Kaart = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Map, opt);
>
> Pijl = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Arrow, opt);

I've declared "Kaart" and "Pijl" als bitmaps at the start of the class but "Map" and "Arrow" remain unrecognised and are red underlined saying that Resource.Drawable does not contain a definition for "Arrow" and "Map".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Resources res = getContext().getResources();
int id = R.drawable.image; 
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
```

This shall return the decoded `Bitmap` or it will return null if the image cannot be decoded.

> NOTE : The `Bitmap` would be different if `"image"` exists in all
>   drawable folders(like ldpi,mdpi,hdpi , etc) . So it's ideal to keep the
>   image in the original `drawable` folder unaltered.